# Dell BiOS update

Tags: powershell, cmd, upgrade, bios

I am working as a helpdesk on my company. New to command lines and PowerShell. I've a company that manages around 100 laptops which I manually upgrade their BIOS. During manual upgrade, it automatically suspends the BitLocker. I've found a silent way to do this on PowerShell through Dell Documentation using this command:

```
Below is an example output from the Latitude E6520 BIOS executable “E6520A05.exe”.
General usage:

Typical Syntax: Filename.exe [/<option1>[=<value1>]] [/<option2>[=<value2>]]
Option - Description:
(none) - Display of graphical user interface for guided update.
/? or /h - Displays this Dell System BIOS Update usage information.
/s - Suppresses all graphical user interfaces of the BIOS System BIOS Update.
/l= - Define a specific path for the Dell System BIOS Update log file.
/f - Override a soft dependency error returned from the Dell System BIOS Update. NOTE: Requires /s option.
/r - Reboot the system to complete the update. NOTE: Requires /s option.
/p= - Provide the BIOS password (if needed) to perform the BIOS update.

Example(s):
Update the system silently: Filename.exe /s
Change from the default log location (example target path: C:\my path with spaces\log.txt)
Filename.exe /l=”C:\my path with spaces\log.txt”
Force update to continue (even on “soft” qualification errors): Filename.exe /s /f"
```

In my case my laptops are DELL Precision 5530, and updated using this command

```
.\Precision_5530_1.25.0.exe /noPause /s /f /l=C:\Temp\BiOS.log
```

My question is our company policy has BitLocker on, and system admin suggested the above command will work fine but find a way to suspend BitLocker before doing that (so we can avoid crashing the laptop that's out of warranty) but also make sure to turn on after the update. I've searched everywhere but could not find relevant information.

Any insight on this would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: "so we can avoid crashing the laptop that's out of warranty" - I wouldn't sweat it: Dell laptops (and pretty much every business-grade laptop out there) has a BIOS/CMOS recovery mode to recover from a corrupted or failed BIOS firmware flash, [for example](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/solved-recover-dell-inspiron-laptop-corrupted-bios-how-roland-ihasz).

Comment: @Dai thank you for your prompt response, just wondering is there a way to silently disable the BitLocker during the execution of exe file?

Comment: Sounds like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/windows-security/suspend-bitlocker-protection-non-microsoft-updates

Answer (score 0):

In powershell:

```
Suspend-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -RebootCount 0
```

Or in a batch file:

```
manage-bde -protectors -disable c:
```